# Scala Regex example not working

Tags: regex, scala

I'm pretty new to scala, and I'm trying to use regex to solve a problem, but I'm getting an error.

I copied an example directly from the docs (2.10.4), and I'm getting the same error.

What am I missing here:

```
println(scala.tools.nsc.Properties.versionString)
val p1 = "ab*c".r
val p2 = "a(b*)c".r

val p1Matches = "abbbc" match {
  case p1() => true
  case _    => false
}
```

produces:

```
version 2.10.4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  scala.util.matching.Regex.unapplySeq(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Lscala/Option;
 at SparkGrep$.argsParser(SparkGrep.scala:67)
 at SparkGrep$.main(SparkGrep.scala:23)
 at SparkGrep.main(SparkGrep.scala)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
...
```

line 67 is the line that says:

```
  case p1() => true
```

for reference this example is copied directly from the unappplyseq example at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex

Update, I have created an example project where this does, in fact work.  I've figured out that it has something to do withmy build process, but I have no idea why.

Here's the build.sbt for the broken project

```
name := "logdata-demo-07-22-2015"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/ typesafe/releases",
  "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"
)

resolvers += "spray" at "http://repo.spray.io/"

val sparkVersion = "1.3.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.1.0",
  "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.3.0"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf")          => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf.*\\.sf$")      => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "log4j.properties"                                  => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.startsWith("meta-inf/services/") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
  case "reference.conf"                                    => MergeStrategy.concat
  case _                                                   => MergeStrategy.first
}

assemblyOutputPath in assembly := new File("output/logdata-demo.jar")
```

Comment: no effect, it seems like the problem is that there's no method with the provided signature at runtime.

Comment: returns `true` for me, scala 2.11.6

Comment: @lostinplace Could this be related to spark? Perhaps they supply an implementation of regex that doesn't work quite the same?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on Scala `2.11.6` everything works fine.
Could be connected to the Scala version.

Best action would be to update to `2.11.x`. If you are stuck with `2.10` you could try `2.10.5`.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

println(scala.tools.nsc.Properties.versionString)
val p1 = "ab*c".r
val p2 = "a(b*)c".r

val p1Matches = "abbbc" match {
  case p1() => true
  case _    => false
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

version 2.11.6
p1: scala.util.matching.Regex = ab*c
p2: scala.util.matching.Regex = a(b*)c
p1Matches: Boolean = true
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the printed version that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code in Scala `2.10.4` and it worked fine.

You should try getting the Scala version in the following way to make sure you're using `2.10.4`:

```
scala.util.Properties.scalaPropOrElse("version.number", "unknown")
  val p1 = "ab*c".r
  val p2 = "a(b*)c".r
  val p1Matches = "abbbc" match {
    case p1() => true
    case _    => false
  }
```

Comment: yeah, I've confirmed that is should work... it just doesn't and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by inappropriate placement of the class files.  They were in a scala 2.11 folder at build time.  moving them to a scala-2.10 folder fixed the issue.

SBT is weird